# how to reach the bytes of a number? and why? C

Tags: c, byte

I know that in order to reach the bytes of a number we should do:

```
unsigned int number=value;
char* bytes = (char*)&number;
```

...but I don't really understand why.

Why do we need to use char *?
Why are we casting here?

Thank you :)

Comment: What exactly is it that you want here?

Comment: I don't understand why we use char *? why dont we use int *?

Comment: a char is a byte, and I dont know why "we" use anything, as what you posted is not real code and certainly not a full program

Comment: Because an `int * ` points to an `int`, which is bigger than a byte.

Comment: ok.. can u please explain why char is a byte?

Comment: @user3169750  Basically this type of casting to find out endianess but certainly not this much code. There is more to it .

Comment: @user3169750 The size of a `char` is 1 byte because the C Standard defines it so.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what your problem is here.

> Why do we need to use char *?

A char is a byte (read: 8 binary numbers 0 or 1) that can represent a decimal value from 0-255 or -128 - +127 in signed form. It is by default signed.

an `int` is bigger then a byte, hence the need to cast it to get a byte.

Not sure without the context why you'd want to, but you can use that to determine endianness. [Related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701624/difference-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-byte-order)

Comment: it is by default whaterver your compiler says it is. on some platforms, char is by default unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get to the bytes of an int, you need a pointer that points at something the size of a byte. A `char` is defined as the size of a byte, so a pointer to a `char` lets you get the individual bytes of an int.

```
int a[10]
int *p_int= &a[0];
p_int++;
```

The `p_int++` increments the variable by the size of an int and so will point to `a[1]`. It increments with 4 bytes.

```
char *p_char= (char *)&a[0];
p_char++;
```

The `p_char++` increments the variable by the size of a char and so will point to the second byte of the integer `a[0]`.