# Python data persistence

Tags: python, data-serialization

Whenever a Python object needs to be stored or sent over a network, it is first serialized. I guess the reason is that the storage and network transfer are both based on bits. I have a stupid question, which is more like a computer science foundation question than a python question. What kind of format do python objects take when they are in cache? Shouldn't they represent themselves as bits? If that's the case, why not just use those bits to store or send the object, and why bother with serialization?

Comment: A quick answer: the *bits* you mention shall be highly platform-dependent.

Comment: @starrify. Can you explain more on this or can you show me an article or book that explains this well? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bit Representation**

The same object can have different representations in *Bits* on different machines:

- Think **endianness** (byte-order)
- and **architecture** (32 bits, 64 bites)

So an object representation in *Bits* on the sender machine could mean nothing, (or worse could mean something else) when received on the receiver.

Take an simple integer, 1025, as an illustration of the problem:

- On Big Endian machine the *Bits* representation is:

  - binary: `00000000 00000000 00000100 00000001`
  - hexadecimal: `0x00000401`
- while on a Little Endian machine:

  - binary: `00000001 00000100 00000000 00000000`
  - hexadecimal `0x01040000`

That's why to understand each other, 2 machines have to agree on a convention, a protocol. For the IP protocol, the convention is to use the network byte order (big-endian) for example.

More on endianness [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701624/difference-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-byte-order)

**Serialization (and Deserialization)**

We can't directly send an object underlying *bit representation* on the network, for the reasons described before, but not only.

An object can make reference to another object, internally, through a pointer (the in-memory address of this second object). This address is, again, **platform-dependent**.

Python solves this using a serialization algorithm called **pickling** that transforms an object hierarchy into a byte-stream. This byte-stream, when sent over a network, is still platform-dependent and that's why a protocol is needed for both ends to understand each other.

[Pickle module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Does that mean the python serialization, e.g. the pickle process converts the bits into another format of bits that can be understood universally by all the machines? On a high level, can you shed some light on how this is implemented?

Comment: @David i updated my answer with a brief explaination on Serialization the python way, pickling

Comment: just did what you said, splitting the comment into two. To understand the idea better, can I make such an analogy. Machines using different bit representation are like two countries using different length unit. For example, country A uses foot, and country B uses passus. Both countries know how to convert bewteen their own units and the commonly know length unit meter. Country A asks country B to manufacture something that's 1 foot long. It's not possible because no one in country B understand how long is 1 foot.

Comment: Continues for the last comment. To make this happen, country A needs to first convert the length into meter (pickling). And then country B can convert that length in meter into passus (unpickling) and start manufacturing. The length unit translations is analogous to the pickling protocol. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @David your analogy would be correct for the endianness problem, the meter representing the network byte-order, the meter being an unit both ends knows how to convert to and from. For pickling though, making such an analogy would oversimplify the problem, in particular the fact that pickling converts an object hierarchy into a byte-stream. I suggest you read the [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) for a better understand of what pickle is about

Answer (score 1):

The key point for [I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) is achieving [interoperability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperability), e.g. the JSON you send over network might need to get transferred over HTTP protocol and then parsed by JavaScript. And the data you store on disk might need to be readable the next time you run Python (different runtime environment, memory allocations, ...).

But for code execution, you usually want to achieve higher [performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_performance) than what would be possible using interoperable formats, e.g. using memory location addresses to access object methods, dict items, ... Or optimizing for [processor cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) as much as possible.

For details how exactly python is implemented, you can have a look at one of the [interpreter implementations](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/6096976956faf761e712c20f15c77d5b0d99d7c7/pypy/interpreter/?at=default) though.